# MonoTouch random crash on device, not on simulator

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, crash-reports, aot

I am thinking this is somehow memory related, but I have done everything I can think of.  I have made sure classes are disposed property.  Maintained hard references at the class level instead of function scope, for things that might be getting GC'd while I am using them, etc.

Basically the app works fine in the simulator, but crashes at the same spot on a real device.  Seems like I get a few different stacks, but they are all around the same place.

I am using a large amount of events in my application.  Too many threads?

> Stacktrace:
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteValue (object)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,object,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract)
>      at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.WriteMemberInfoProperty
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,object,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract)
>      at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,object,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract)
>      at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,object,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract)
>      at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.IWrappedCollection,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract)
>      at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,object,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract)
>      at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.WriteMemberInfoProperty
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,object,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract)
>      at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,object,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract)
>      at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,object,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract)
>      at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,object)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,object)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,object)    at
>   RestSharp.Serializers.JsonSerializer.Serialize (object) [0x0001c] in
>   /Users/sonmez56/Projects/TrackAbout.Mono/RestSharp/RestSharp/Serializers/JsonSerializer.cs:64
>   at RestSharp.RestRequest.AddBody (object,string) [0x00019] in
>   /Users/sonmez56/Projects/TrackAbout.Mono/RestSharp/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs:203
>   at RestSharp.RestRequest.AddBody (object) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/sonmez56/Projects/TrackAbout.Mono/RestSharp/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs:232
>   at
>   TrackAboutMonoCore.Services.TrackAboutAPIRequestBuilder/TARestRequest.WithBody
>   (T) <0x00097>   at
>   TrackAboutMonoCore.Services.ActionsService.CustomerSetVolume
>   (int,System.Collections.Generic.List`1<TrackAboutMonoCore.Models.Asset>,System.Action`1>)
>   [0x00000] in
>   /Users/sonmez56/Projects/TrackAbout.Mono/TrackAboutMonoCore/Services/ActionsService.cs:24
>   at TrackAboutMonoCore.Controllers.LocateController.Save
>   (object,System.EventArgs) [0x00055] in
>   /Users/sonmez56/Projects/TrackAbout.Mono/TrackAboutMonoCore/Controllers/LocateController.cs:64
>   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIBarButtonItem/Callback.Call
>   (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject) [0x00010] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIBarButtonItem.cs:23 
>   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>   at
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0004c]
>   in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
>   at TrackAboutIOS.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/sonmez56/Projects/TrackAbout.Mono/TrackAboutIOS/TrackAboutIOS/Main.cs:16
>   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
>
> Native stacktrace:
>
> 0   TrackAboutIOS                       0x01d20618
>   mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 280  1   TrackAboutIOS
>   0x01d45bd4 sigabrt_signal_handler + 180   2   libsystem_c.dylib
>   0x376647ed _sigtramp + 48     3   libsystem_c.dylib
>   0x3765a20f pthread_kill + 54  4   libsystem_c.dylib
>   0x3765329f abort + 94     5   TrackAboutIOS
>   0x01e394ac monoeg_g_log + 208     6   TrackAboutIOS
>   0x01d11664 get_numerous_trampoline + 160  7   TrackAboutIOS
>   0x01d11aac mono_aot_get_imt_thunk + 56    8   TrackAboutIOS
>   0x01dbdc50 initialize_imt_slot + 112  9   TrackAboutIOS
>   0x01dbf1c4 build_imt_slots + 1124     10  TrackAboutIOS
>   0x01dbf32c mono_vtable_build_imt_slot + 120   11  TrackAboutIOS
>   0x01d236fc mono_convert_imt_slot_to_vtable_slot + 292     12 
>   TrackAboutIOS                       0x01d23974 common_call_trampoline
>   + 284     13  TrackAboutIOS                       0x01d21c60 mono_vcall_trampoline + 228  14  TrackAboutIOS
>   0x00934198 generic_trampoline_vcall + 136     15  TrackAboutIOS
>   0x00b9fec4
>   Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonSerializerInternalWriter_SerializeValue_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_object_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract + 1116   16  TrackAboutIOS                       0x00ba13bc Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonSerializerInternalWriter_WriteMemberInfoProperty_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_object_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract + 1712    17  TrackAboutIOS                       0x00ba2a70 Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonSerializerInternalWriter_SerializeObject_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_object_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonObjectContract_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract + 1784   18  TrackAboutIOS                       0x00ba0124 Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonSerializerInternalWriter_SerializeValue_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_object_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract + 1724  19  TrackAboutIOS                       0x00ba3ec0 Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonSerializerInternalWriter_SerializeList_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_Newtonsoft_Json_Utilities_IWrappedCollection_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonArrayContract_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract + 2520    20  TrackAboutIOS                       0x00ba041c Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonSerializerInternalWriter_SerializeValue_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_object_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract + 2484  21  TrackAboutIOS                       0x00ba13bc Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonSerializerInternalWriter_WriteMemberInfoProperty_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_object_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract + 1712    22  TrackAboutIOS                       0x00ba2a70 Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonSerializerInternalWriter_SerializeObject_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_object_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonObjectContract_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract + 1784   23  TrackAboutIOS                       0x00ba0124 Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonSerializerInternalWriter_SerializeValue_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_object_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract + 1724  24  TrackAboutIOS                       0x00b9f70c Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonSerializerInternalWriter_Serialize_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_object
>   + 356     25  TrackAboutIOS                       0x00b2c52c Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_SerializeInternal_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_object
>   + 300     26  TrackAboutIOS                       0x00b2c3b4 Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Serialize_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_object
>   + 156     27  TrackAboutIOS                       0x012010c0 RestSharp_Serializers_JsonSerializer_Serialize_object + 452  28 
>   TrackAboutIOS                       0x011f8ad0
>   RestSharp_RestRequest_AddBody_object_string + 396     29  TrackAboutIOS
>   0x011f8e4c RestSharp_RestRequest_AddBody_object + 152     30 
>   TrackAboutIOS                       0x011d3c64
>   TrackAboutMonoCore_Services_TrackAboutAPIRequestBuilder_TARestRequest_WithBody_T_T
>   + 152     31  TrackAboutIOS                       0x011d22d4 TrackAboutMonoCore_Services_ActionsService_CustomerSetVolume_int_System_Collections_Generic_List_1_TrackAboutMonoCore_Models_Asset_System_Action_1_RestSharp_RestResponse_1_TrackAbout_Rest_Models_TARestResponse
>   + 328     32  TrackAboutIOS                       0x011ce3bc TrackAboutMonoCore_Controllers_LocateController_Save_object_System_EventArgs
>   + 960     33  TrackAboutIOS                       0x0139003c MonoTouch_UIKit_UIBarButtonItem_Callback_Call_MonoTouch_Foundation_NSObject
>   + 96  34  TrackAboutIOS                       0x008b0450 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr
>   + 200     35  TrackAboutIOS                       0x01d05834 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1644   36  TrackAboutIOS
>   0x01dbd09c mono_runtime_invoke + 128  37  TrackAboutIOS
>   0x01e4c054 monotouch_trampoline + 3436    38  CoreFoundation
>   0x30c7f3fd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 52    39
>   UIKit                               0x3353efaf -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 62    40  UIKit
>   0x3360476b -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 118
>     41  CoreFoundation                      0x30c7f3fd -[NSObject
>   performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 52  42  UIKit
>   0x3353efaf -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 62     43 
>   UIKit                               0x3353ef6b -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30    44  UIKit
>   0x3353ef49 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44  45  UIKit
>   0x3353ecb9 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] +
>   492   46  UIKit                               0x3353f5f1 -[UIControl
>   touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 476    47  UIKit
>   0x3353dad3 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 318    48  UIKit
>   0x3353d4c1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 380   49  UIKit
>   0x3352383d -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356  50  UIKit
>   0x335230e3 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5826   51  GraphicsServices
>   0x33e1322b PurpleEventCallback + 882  52  CoreFoundation
>   0x30cf9523 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 38  53  CoreFoundation                      0x30cf94c5 **CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 140   54  CoreFoundation                      0x30cf8313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1370    55  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x30c7b4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300     56  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x30c7b36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104   57  GraphicsServices
>
>   0x33e12439 GSEventRunModal + 136  58  UIKit
>
>   0x33551e7d UIApplicationMain + 1080   59  TrackAboutIOS
>
>   0x01696c74
>   wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string**_intptr_intptr
>   + 240     60  TrackAboutIOS                       0x00098420 TrackAboutIOS_Application_Main_string__ + 152    61  TrackAboutIOS
>   0x008b0450
>   wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr
>   + 200     62  TrackAboutIOS                       0x01d05834 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1644   63  TrackAboutIOS
>   0x01dbd09c mono_runtime_invoke + 128  64  TrackAboutIOS
>   0x01dc16b4 mono_runtime_exec_main + 436   65  TrackAboutIOS
>   0x01dc1a74 mono_runtime_run_main + 756    66  TrackAboutIOS
>   0x01d0c744 mono_jit_exec + 140    67  TrackAboutIOS
>   0x01e41110 main + 2288    68  TrackAboutIOS
>   0x0009826c start + 52

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's normally an exception **type** and **message** before the line:

> Stacktrace:

It usually provides a good hint of the issue. Now the native stack trace also gives a clue here:

> 0x01e394ac monoeg_g_log + 208 6 TrackAboutIOS
>
> 0x01d11664 get_numerous_trampoline + 160 7 TrackAboutIOS

The first line tells us something was printed (or at least it tried to print) in your logs. It you check your device's log (e.g. using Xcode or `mtouch --logdev`) you should see the message.

The next line makes me think you're running out of trampolines (the error message will tell you which type). Here are the [instructions](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/troubleshooting#Ran_out_of_trampolines_of_type_0) on how to augment the number of trampolines available for your application.

Note: in case this is not trampoline-related please edit your question to add the exception type/message and the content of your device's log.

Comment: Thank you.  I spent so many hours on this.  So funny, just a minute before you answered, I checked my device log and saw the out of trampolines message.  That seems to have fixed the issue.